# how to use JavaScript to automatically input a question into the dialogue box of Bing Chat and then send it automatically

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, bing

I want to use JavaScript to automatically input a question into the dialogue box of Bing Chat(https://www.bing.com/search?q=Bing+AI&showconv=1&FORM=hpcodx) and then send it automatically. However, after using JavaScript to input the question, I am unable to send it. How can I achieve the automatic sending of the question after inputting it into the dialogue box of Bing Chat using JavaScript?

I used these javascript but faild

```
document.querySelector('cib-serp').shadowRoot.querySelector('#cib-action-bar-main').shadowRoot.querySelector('#searchbox').value="Hello world";

document.querySelector('cib-serp').shadowRoot.querySelector('#cib-action-bar-main').shadowRoot.querySelector('.button.primary').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
edgDriver.execute_script(
   'document.querySelector(\"#b_sydConvCont > cib-serp\")
            .shadowRoot
            .querySelector(\"#cib-action-bar-main\")
            .shadowRoot.querySelector(\"div > div.main-container.body-2 > div.input-container.as-ghost-placement > cib-text-input\")
            .shadowRoot
            .querySelector(\"#searchbox\")
            .value="Hello world";'
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).